# UnsupportedOperationException on Android 3.2 when selecting text (AppCompat 21.0.3)

Tags: android, exception, android-appcompat

I'm just preparing to release my app after updating to AppCompat 21.0.3. While testing on various emulators, I found that there is a crash on Android 3.2 anytime I try to select text within my WebView.

This does not appear to happen on 2.3.3 or 4.0.3 emulator (on 2.3.3 it selects the text, and allows me to touch to copy. On 4.0.3 it shows the action mode, which is also what I expected on 3.2). Has anyone run into something similar? Is there any fix, or do we have to wait for an AppCompat update?

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuWrapperFactory.wrapSupportMenu(MenuWrapperFactory.java:39)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.getMenuWrapper(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:179)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:154)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1297)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.startSupportActionModeFromWindow(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:648)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.startActionMode(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:99)
        at android.support.v7.widget.WindowCallbackWrapper.startActionMode(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.startActionMode(ToolbarActionBar.java:206)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.startSupportActionMode(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:581)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateHC.startActionModeForChild(ActionBarActivityDelegateHC.java:62)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout.startActionModeForChild(NativeActionModeAwareLayout.java:44)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:553)
        at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:3157)
        at android.webkit.WebView.setUpSelect(WebView.java:4935)
        at android.webkit.WebView.selectText(WebView.java:3957)
        at android.webkit.WebView.selectText(WebView.java:3950)
        at android.webkit.WebView.performLongClick(WebView.java:3939)
        at android.webkit.WebView$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(WebView.java:7752)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Same thing happens when I attempt to select text from the Toolbar's SearchView.

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuWrapperFactory.wrapSupportMenu(MenuWrapperFactory.java:39)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.getMenuWrapper(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:179)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:154)
        ...
        at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:3157)
        at android.widget.TextView.startSelectionActionMode(TextView.java:8306)
        at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:8206)
        at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:11910)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

**Edit:** Still happening in AppCompat v22. My current solution is to simply disable selecting text for those who are effected, like so:

```
// There is a bug in Android 3.0-3.2 that causes selecting text to crash.
// Temporary fix is to disable long-click/text-selection for API 11-13.
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
    myWebView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    myWebView.setLongClickable(false);
}
```

Comment: I've seen this too on 3.2.1

Comment: got a crash report about similar issue

Comment: got this error from 3.2, Samsung SHW-M380 Galaxy Tab 10.1 tablet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in support library 22.1.0 (see: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80434)